# How does one represent differential geometry on computers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, differential-geometry

So something that I've wondered is that how does one represent differential geometry concepts on a computer, since a lot of the concepts seem "continuous" and "derivative" (such as having $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$s as bases, rather than  unit vectors).

Comment: It depends on application. What do you want to build with it?

Comment: @mathreadler No I just want to understand how the concepts are discretized in general, since manifolds don't have coordinate systems except through charts.

Comment: You can pick your favourite way to do it. If you don't know any way to do it, some refreshed linear algebra could help.

Answer (score 0):

[Keenan Crane](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/) at CMU has written an [excellent introduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DGPDEC/) to the subject of discrete differential geometry, from an applications perspective.

The scope is far too vast to cover in an answer, but the high-order bit is that there are various ways to discretize different notions from differential geometry, and the name of the game is to choose the "right" set of discretizations, in order to make the whole theory coherent.